# Как удалить голос из музыки с помощью python?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть python библиотеки для удаления голоса из музыки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можно попробовать разложить звук на частоты с помощью FFT (фаст Фурье трансформ) и убрать диапазон частот, в котором обычно бывает голос. Способ не очень хороший, но простой и понятный. Дальше уже нейросетями, может и есть готовые решения, надо искать.

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления голоса нужно смешать трек с инвертированным.

Если стерео и голос посередине, то один канал инвертируешь и сводишь всё в моно, но не сложением.

Если моно, то дублируешь канал инвертируешь и смешиваешь.

Инвертировать фазу в pyaudio можно через `audio_data = [-x for x in audio_data]`